# Is my interpretation of ADF and KPSS correct?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller, kpss-test

I am new to time series analysis, and I am trying to interpret the ADF and KPSS results. Is my interpretation of stationary correct?

```
# ADF
test = adfuller(values, autolag='AIC')
print('ADF Statistic: {}'.format(test[0]))
print('p-value: {}'.format(test[1]))
print('Critical values: {}'.format(test[4]))
print('Stationary: {}'.format(test[0] <= test[4]['1%'] and test[1] <= 0.05))

# KPSS Level
test = kpss(values, regression='c')
print('\nKPSS Level Statistic: {}'.format(test[0]))
print('p-value: {}'.format(test[1]))
print('Critical values: {}'.format(test[3]))
print('Stationary: {}'.format(test[0] >= test[3]['1%'] and test[1] <= 0.05))

# KPSS Trend
test = kpss(values, regression='ct')
print('\nKPSS Trend Statistic: {}'.format(test[0]))
print('p-value: {}'.format(test[1]))
print('Critical values: {}'.format(test[3]))
print('Stationary: {}'.format(test[0] >= test[3]['1%'] and test[1] <= 0.05))
```

Output:

```
ADF Statistic: -9.021956870636977
p-value: 5.743381257670514e-15
Critical values: {'1%': -3.431646340212922, '5%': -2.8621128433695495, '10%': -2.567074925018478}
Stationary: True

KPSS Level Statistic: 0.7433244031234921
p-value: 0.01
Critical values: {'10%': 0.347, '5%': 0.463, '2.5%': 0.574, '1%': 0.739}
Stationary: True

KPSS Trend Statistic: 0.13916440333034322
p-value: 0.06265851235121625
Critical values: {'10%': 0.119, '5%': 0.146, '2.5%': 0.176, '1%': 0.216}
Stationary: False
```